# Multiple limits in fitting and toy generation in zfit

Tags: python, zfit

I have a running model with a pdf in zfit from where I want to generate toys from and after also fit the pdf to the toys. However I was wondering how to exclude certain areas in the toy generation as well as in the fitting after. More clear this means using multiple limits so that I have multiple ranges in where my fit and toy generations runs (simultaniosely).
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using **multiple limits** by adding `Space`s, (*minus a remark on fitting range, see below*)

I assume you define your model and data in a way like

```
obs = zfit.Space('x', (..,..))

model = zfit.pdf.Foo(obs=obs,...)
data = zfit.Data....(obs=obs,...)
```

To define a single Space with multiple limits, do

```
obs1a = zfit.Space('x', (..., ...))
obs1b = zfit.Space('x', (..., ...))
obs = obs1a + obs1b
```

Note that the observable `'x'` is in both cases the same and therefore the `Space` will be added and not extended to higher dimensions.

### "Fitting Range"

Just to clarify, there is actually "no such thing as a *fitting range*". There are two ranges that matter:

- the data range which are the cuts applied to the data
- the normalization range: Integral over it is 1 (by definition)

Often, this two coincide and are named fitting range. Sometimes though the normalization range can be different (*e.g. from previous fits to an extended range to the left/right*) and "fitting range" is often used equivalently for the "data range" since this defines, *which* data points are used in the likelihood.